# Visualizar sumas acumuladas en DataGridView C#

Tags: c#

Necesito visualizar en un datagridview cada bucle calculado, es decir, si se ingresan 3 años, que aparezcan los subtotales de cada año.
Cada bucle por cada calculo que haga que ponga en el dgv el numero de año, y el monto total seria suficiente.

Además del form hice el siguiente código pero no me estaría funcionado:

```
>     
namespace UserInterface
{
    public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
    {
        public frmPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtAños.Text = "";
            txtImporte.Text = "";
            txtPorcentaje.Text = "";
            txtTotal.Text = "";
        }

        public void CalcularPorcentaje()
        {
            decimal subtotal = 0;
            decimal total = 0;
            int años = Convert.ToInt32(txtAños.Text);
            int porcentaje = Convert.ToInt32(txtPorcentaje.Text);
            decimal importe = Convert.ToDecimal(txtImporte.Text);
            
            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < años; i++)
                {
                    

                    subtotal += (importe * (1 / porcentaje));

                    if (i == años)
                    {
                        total = subtotal;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subtotal += (subtotal * (1 / porcentaje));
                    }

                    total = subtotal;
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }          
            
            
            txtAños.Text = años.ToString();
            txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();
            

            DataGridViewRow fila = new DataGridViewRow();
            fila.CreateCells(dgvCalculo);
            //fila.Cells[0].Value = años.ToString();
            //fila.Cells[1].Value = txtTotal.ToString();

            //dgvCalculo.Rows.Add(dgvCalculo);

        }

        private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalcularPorcentaje();

        }

    }
}
```

El bloque de codigo del datagridview me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien podría asistirme porque la verdad no me doy cuenta que hago mal.

Gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: vamos por partes, un error por vez.. si total te da 0, entonces o el bucle no se ejecuta, o en el bucle total queda en 0... seguiste el bucle a ver porque total queda en 0?

Comment: en la primer operación no calcula el porcentaje o no lo almacena en subtotal, por ende al repetirse el bucle, subtotal es 0 y ya todo es 0

Comment: Y bueno... y porque no podes solucionar eso? si da 0 siempre, es porque la cuenta da 0. Pero no tenemos informacion de que numeros estas metiendo ahi como para saber que pasa...

Comment: Perdon, ya vi que parte del código estaba mal...ahora necesitaría por favor lo del datagridview

Comment: bueno.. y que error te da eso? centra la pregunta en un problema especifico con toda la informacion necesaria para poder saber que pasa.. no me funciona, no nos sirve como error... pueden ser mil cosas...

Comment: Ahí edité el post inicial y título, agregué una imagen del error

Comment: que es dgvCalculo? es un template de filas valido? como lo hiciste? donde lo definiste?

Comment: es un DataGridView, es justamente donde necesito se vean los resultados. Esta en el form de la interfaz del usuario final

Comment: Pero es donde queres guardar los datos? y tiene ya las columnas creadas? Pq el error dice que no tenes columnas...

Answer (score 0):

tienes que crear las columnas del Data GridView. Puedes hacerlo desde el editor de Visual Studio. Si lo haces con VS, no tendrás que modificar tu código. También puedes hacerlo desde el constructor.
Te recomiendo un usar el DataSource del GridView, puedes asignarle cualquier objeto que implemente un IEnumerable. Puedes crear una clase especifica para almacenar los datos que necesitas en el grid

```
namespace UserInterface
{
    public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
    {
        class Calculo
        {
            public decimal Años;
            public decimal Importe;
            public decimal Porcentaje;
            public decimal Total;
        }

        private List<Calculo> calculos;
        
        public frmPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            calculos = new List<Calculo>();
            
            //te recomiendo hacer esto desde el designer de visual studio
            dvgCalculo.Columns.Add("Años","Importe","Porcentaje", "Total");
            
            
        }
        private void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtAños.Text = "";
            txtImporte.Text = "";
            txtPorcentaje.Text = "";
            txtTotal.Text = "";
            calculos.Clear();
        }

        public void CalcularPorcentaje()
        {
            decimal subtotal = 0;
            decimal total = 0;
            int años = Convert.ToInt32(txtAños.Text);
            int porcentaje = Convert.ToInt32(txtPorcentaje.Text);
            decimal importe = Convert.ToDecimal(txtImporte.Text);

            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < años; i++)
                {


                    subtotal += (importe * (1 / porcentaje));

                    if (i == años)
                    {
                        total = subtotal;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subtotal += (subtotal * (1 / porcentaje));
                    }

                    total = subtotal;

                    calculos.Add(new Calculo()
                    {
                        Años = i,
                        Importe = importe,
                        Porcentaje = porcentaje,
                        Total = subtotal
                    });
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


            txtAños.Text = años.ToString();
            txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();
        }

        private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalcularPorcentaje();
            //Tratar con las rows y cells de un datadrid  es un dolor de cabeza
            // usa el datasource a menos que necesites modificar valores o usar controles
            dvgCalculo.DataSource = calculos;

        }

    }
}
}
```